# ReadOnly DatePicker in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, validation, datepicker, readonly

I am making an application in Silverlight 3.0. In that application i am using DatePicker control as

```
<TextBlock FontSize="13" Height="23" Name="txtFromDate" Text="FromDate" Width="40" Canvas.Left="444" Canvas.Top="6" />
<controls:DatePicker Name="fromdatePicker" Height="23" Width="110" Canvas.Left="550" Canvas.Top="4"  />
```

Here i don't want to enter date manually(Means the textblock txtFromDate should be read only.)And the value in text block will be whatever date is selected from calender. I am not getting how to do it? Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using a nice MVVM approach:

Bind the `SeletectedDate` of your date picker to a `DateTime` property of your ViewModel (two-way binding):

```
<sdk:DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding MyDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Bind the Text property of your `TextBlock` to the same property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyDate}" />
```